# How do i modify the case where function to give me the total?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query that computes the total project cost from these two tables (overtime is 1.5* contracted hourly rate)

```
employee id .   name .     contracted_hours position contracted_sal
1                Eve         40             ceo         25000
2               Alice       40              pm          10000
3               Bob         15              director .  9000
4               Frank       30              pm .        5000
5               David       35              tech .      17500
6               Carol .     20              tech .      10000



project_id    employee_id      assigned_hours
1             2                40
1 .           5 .              20
1 .           6 .              10
2 .           4 .              20
2 .           5 .              20
2 .           6 .              10
```

Tried the code below, 'got a "select" is not valid at this position error'

```sql
SELECT project_id,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(assigned_hours) <= contracted_hours THEN 
            SUM(assigned_hours * (contracted_salary/contracted_hours)) 
        ELSE SUM(
                SUM(
                    assigned_hours - (assigned_hours - contracted_hours) * (contracted_salary/contracted_hours) + (((assigned_hours - contracted_hours) * (contracted_salary/contracted_hours)*1.5)/2
                )
            )
    END as total_cost
FROM tbl_employees e
JOIN tbl_projects p
    ON e.employee_id = p.employee_id
GROUP BY project_id;
```

If you work out the math project 1 should be 25625 and project 2 should be 20625.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CASE` expression is invalid syntax wise, but also incorrect. What you want to do is `SUM` the cost for each employee on a project based on their assigned hours compared to their contracted hours. You can do that with this query:

```
select project_id,
    round(
    sum(
    case when assigned_hours <= contracted_hours then assigned_hours * (contracted_salary/contracted_hours)
    else contracted_salary + (assigned_hours - contracted_hours) * (contracted_salary * 1.5/contracted_hours)
    end)
    ,2) as total_cost
from tbl_employees e
join tbl_projects p
on e.employee_id = p.employee_id
group by project_id;
```

Output:

```
project_id  total_cost
1           25000
2           18333.33
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6HTGzyHWqzYZjtfUTzyYYH/0)

**Note**

For the sample data in your question, your expected results are incorrect, if you look at project 1, the cost should be

```
10000 (employee 2) + 20 * 17500/35 (employee 5) + 10 * 10000/20 (employee 6)
```

which comes to `25000`, not `25625`, and for project 2, the cost should be

```
20 * 5000 / 30 (employee 4) + 20 * 17500/35 (employee 5) + 10 * 10000/20 (employee 6)
```

which comes to `18333.33`, not `20625`.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Comment: Thanks Nick it runs perfectly on dbfiddle but on MySQL i get 25000 and 20000 instead of your answer.

Comment: @NeverQuit101 are you running with the same data? The math that the query is doing is correct (I've included project2 in my answer as well now and it works out correctly)

Answer (score -1):

You have a missing `)` in the `ELSE` part of the `CASE`. I guess this gives you the syntax error.

Eventough I am not sure if you really want to have nested aggregate functions (and if, I would also be suprised if it works and is not an error on its own).

Comment: This should be  a comment, not an answer.